# Image does not save as the actual image file but a blank image file

Tags: php, image, get, save, magento-1.9

could someone please help me?

When i try to save an image in the new folder location it saves but as an empty image file. i've tried to use $_FILES['pic']['name'] but it doesn't do anything so i've been using $_GET['pic'] . 
It was working yesterday but for some reason it isn't now.
Could you please look at my code because i don't know where i'm going wrong

Thanks in advance :)

Code to save the image file:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["formCheck"])){
    if (isset($_GET["pic"]) ) {
        $link= $_GET["pic"];
        echo "name: " . $link . "<br>";
        $extension = end(explode('.', $_GET["pic"]));
        $hashedimg = md5($link.time()) . "." . $extension;

        echo $hashedimg . "<br>";
        $destdir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'library' . DS;
        echo "dir: " .$destdir . "<br>";
        $img=file_get_contents($hashedimg);
        file_put_contents($destdir.substr($hashedimg, strrpos($hashedimg,'/')), $img);

        echo "end: " . $extension . "<br>";
        echo "fileloc: " . $destdir . $hashedimg . "<br>";
        $fileloc = $destdir . $hashedimg;

        $_GET["pic"] = $fileloc;
        echo $_GET["pic"];              
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because i was using `method="GET"` and not POST. to fix it change the get to post instead and then `$_FILES['pic']['name']` will work